# odoo interface not correctly displaying after installing nightly package on windows

Tags: odoo

[image]for one of my projects I needed to deploy the POS module on one of my client's computer, so I followed the following link for the Packaged installers on a windows system.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-packaged

after the installation, when i tried to open odoo on localhost:8069 it would not give any error but would show the interface of the odoo imroperly, maybe the css or less files were not correctly loaded, i installed lessc but it did not solve my problem. my browser has javascript enable but still the interface is not correctly loaded

so if anyone help me regarding this, would appreciate it.

here are the last lines of the log file:

2017-01-18 16:57:41,072 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 16:57:41] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 16:58:31,105 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 16:58:31] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 16:59:19,237 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 16:59:19] "POST /calendar/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 16:59:21,144 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 16:59:21] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:00:11,176 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:00:11] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:01:01,223 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:01:01] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:01:51,285 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:01:51] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:02:41,329 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:02:41] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:03:31,361 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:03:31] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:04:04,611 4768 INFO testdb openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_autovacuum: GC'd 0 user log entries
    2017-01-18 17:04:19,220 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:04:19] "POST /calendar/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:04:21,392 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:04:21] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:05:11,437 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:05:11] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:06:01,469 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:06:01] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:06:51,500 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:06:51] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:07:41,546 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:07:41] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:08:31,579 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:08:31] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:09:19,377 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:09:19] "POST /calendar/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:09:21,627 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:09:21] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:10:11,657 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:10:11] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:11:01,704 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:11:01] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:11:51,790 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:11:51] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:12:41,979 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:12:41] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:13:32,026 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:13:32] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:14:19,224 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:14:19] "POST /calendar/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:14:22,069 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:14:22] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:15:12,099 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:15:12] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:16:02,147 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:16:02] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:16:52,194 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:16:52] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:17:42,233 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:17:42] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:18:19,141 4768 INFO test_odoo openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_autovacuum: GC'd 0 user log entries
    2017-01-18 17:18:32,266 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:18:32] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:19:19,234 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:19:19] "POST /calendar/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:19:22,312 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:19:22] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:20:12,351 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:20:12] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:20:12,351 4768 ERROR test_odoo openerp.service.server: Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 63941)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "SocketServer.pyc", line 593, in process_request_thread
      File "SocketServer.pyc", line 334, in finish_request
      File "SocketServer.pyc", line 651, in **init**
      File "SocketServer.pyc", line 710, in finish
      File "socket.pyc", line 279, in close
      File "socket.pyc", line 303, in flush
    error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    2017-01-18 17:20:49,263 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:20:49] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2017-01-18 17:21:39,305 4768 INFO test_odoo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 17:21:39] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Open the interface and post a picture of the issue. Also, post part of the server logs here so that we can see whether you get any 404 errors.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas I have updated the question with the log and the screen shot.... :)